# How do I get query parameters in the URL

Tags: url, dart

In Dart I am working on a web game. In this I would need a function where I can get data from the URL, in the same way that you would get it in PHP. How would I do this?

Say I, for example, append the following to my URL when I load my web game: `?id=15&randomNumber=3.14`. How can I get them in Dart either as a raw string (preferred) or in some other format?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You can use the Uri class from dart:core
https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/dartdoc-viewer/dart-core.Uri

ie:

```dart
main() {
  print(Uri.base.toString()); // http://localhost:8082/game.html?id=15&randomNumber=3.14
  print(Uri.base.query);  // id=15&randomNumber=3.14
  print(Uri.base.queryParameters['randomNumber']); // 3.14
}
```

Comment: Invalid when the parameter contains a colon.

Comment: When on web, you should do this on the main function as query parameters (at least in my case) somehow were deleted once flutter navigates to a route.

Comment: @noeleven parameters in URL shall be url-encoded, using Uri.encodeComponent.

Answer (score 19):

```
import 'dart:html';   

void doWork(){  
  var uri = Uri.dataFromString(window.location.href); //converts string to a uri    
  Map<String, String> params = uri.queryParameters; // query parameters automatically populated
  var param1 = params['param1']; // return value of parameter "param1" from uri
  var param2 = params['param2'];
  print(jsonEncode(params)); //can use returned parameters to encode as json
}
```

Comment: Add some explanation for your code would be preferred.

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to problem, it is highly recommended that you provide additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question. Code only answers typically become useless in the long-run because future viewers experiencing similar problems cannot understand the reasoning behind the solution.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions guys, I will keep these things in mind next time

Answer (score 4):

Import `'dart:html'` then you can use `window.location...`

Comment: thank you!
for other people:

Location currentLocation = window.location;
print(currentLocation.href); // 'http://www.example.com:80/'

Comment: What's `Location`?

Comment: A class in `dart:html` and `window.location` returns an instance of that class. https://dartpad.dartlang.org/79fadf90240c5efd1aeaff80e9187873